# How to get tags from textfield?

Tags: android, algorithm, tags, uitextfield

I have a textfield in android called TagField.
I have an array of Strings called ListOfTags.

I enter a few words separated by spaces into Tagfield and require the function to extract the tags and store it into ListOfTags.

The algorithm I have in mind is:-

1. Store the string from the field into a String object
2. To first locate positions of all the spaces and store it in an array
3. Use the positions to extract sub strings from the main string
4. Store each sub string into ListOFStrings

My Question is, Is there a more efficient method?
Since I am using a lot of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved as-

```
String str = tagField.getText().toString();//get string from the editText.
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");//regular expression which separates the tags.
List<String> listOfTags = Arrays.asList(strArray);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Neat and efficient (y)